# How to echo this entire code to .bashrc without leaving out characters/strings?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal, echo

How can I echo this entire piece of code to .bashrc without leaving out a single character?

```
# automatic logging of terminal input/output
test "$(ps -ocommand= -p $PPID | awk '{print $1}')" == 'script' || (script -f -q /home/user/.logs/terminal/manjaro/$(date +"%Y-%m- %d_%H:%M:%S")_terminal.log)
```

When I attempt to enter the following into terminal:

```
echo "the above code" >> ~/.bashrc
```

I get the following appended to .bashrc which is nothing like "the above code", its short about 45 or so characters.

```
# automatic logging of terminal input/output
test script == 'script' || (script -f -q /home/user/.logs/terminal/manjaro/2019-05- 08_09:09:19_terminal.log)
```

As you can see, it's leaving out A LOT of the original code. I understand this has a lot to do with the number of different quotations and placement, but without altering my code much, or at least to the point where it can still function as its intended, how can I go about getting this to echo to the file properly?

Thank you for every nanosecond of your time.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your echo'd string with single quotes ' instead of double "